# Why doesn't overflow-y:visible look the same as overflow:visible

Tags: css

This is a mock up of a menu i have

**HTML**

```
Menu 1 (overflow:hidden)
<div class='menu'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Item 1
      <ul>
        <li>submenu 1</li>
        <li>submenu 2</li>
        <li>submenu 3</li>
        <li>submenu 4</li>
        <li>submenu 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br/><br/>
Menu 2 (overflow:hidden; overflow-y visible)
<div class='menu menu2'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Item 1
      <ul>
        <li>submenu 1</li>
        <li>submenu 2</li>
        <li>submenu 3</li>
        <li>submenu 4</li>
        <li>submenu 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br/><br/>
Menu 3 (overflow-x:hidden;)
<div class='menu3'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Item 1
      <ul>
        <li>submenu 1</li>
        <li>submenu 2</li>
        <li>submenu 3</li>
        <li>submenu 4</li>
        <li>submenu 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br/><br/>
Menu 4 (overflow:visible;)
<div class='menu menu4'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Item 1
      <ul>
        <li>submenu 1</li>
        <li>submenu 2</li>
        <li>submenu 3</li>
        <li>submenu 4</li>
        <li>submenu 5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu            {border:1px solid #000000; overflow:hidden;}
.menu ul         {list-style:none; margin:5px 5px; padding:0; position:relative}
.menu li         {display:inline-block}
.menu li::after  {content: " | ";}
.menu ul ul      {position:absolute}
.menu ul ul li   {display:block;}
.menu2           {overflow-y:visible}
.menu4           {overflow:visible}

.menu3           {border:1px solid #FF0000;overflow-x:hidden}
.menu3 ul         {list-style:none; margin:5px 5px; padding:0; position:relative}
.menu3 li         {display:inline-block}
.menu3 li::after  {content: " | ";}
.menu3 ul ul      {position:absolute}
.menu3 ul ul li   {display:block;}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fm695fd/5/)

Now the idea is that menu item 1 has a sub menu which is triggered to appear via javascript and the submenu is supposed to go outside the box. because this menu is supposed to be responsive i assume the `overflow` was set in the template for a reason and i want to avoid altering the template as much as i can.

Now as you can see with the code the submenu in `Menu 1` is hidden in the box, when i go to override the `overflow-y` property in `Menu 2` to be it's [default value](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) (which is the same as [`overflow`'s](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_overflow.asp)) it's still hidden and there's a scroll box.

now just in case if there was something weird in `overflow` is still set for the y axis i went and copied the `menu` class for `Menu 3` but instead of doing `overflow:hidden` i just did `overflow-x:hidden;` but that still have be a scrollbar. `Menu 4` shows how if `overflow` is set to visible (the default value) i have no scroll bar and my submenu goes out of the box as it should.

My question is why doesn't `overflow-y:visible` look the same as `overflow:visible`? to my understanding, `overflow:visible` is just `overflow-x:visible; overflow-y:visible` much like how `border:1px solid #000000` is the same as setting all the border sides's width, style and color one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are part of CSS3 (while plain `overflow` is CSS2), and are still somewhat experimental.  The rules for what happens when one value is a "scrolling value" (which includes `hidden`) and the other is `visible` are complex, and frankly confusing.

From the [CSS3 Overflow Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/):

> 2. ... if one cascaded values [sic] is one of the scrolling values and the other is ‘visible’, then computed values are the cascaded values with ‘visible’ changed to ‘hidden’.

This *seems* to justify the behavior you're seeing, but I don't understand why it was designed that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow: visible;
```

does not clip content and can be shown out side of content box but for

```
overflow-y; visible;
```

content clipped against content box with overflow auto default

Answer (score 0):

I made a revised [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8r2h51j8/) but the main issue I found is that the style for `.menu` was applied to all four menus and that part of its definition was `overflow: hiddden`, so you were basically getting a conflict with Menu 2. Deleting `overflow: hidden` from `.menu` in the first line of your CSS makes both Menu 2 and Menu 4 have the same behavior as you were expecting.